# Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp

Tags: javascript, android, webrtc, phpwebsocket

I have implemented WebRTC for video-audio call through browser. I am using the latest `adapter.js`. I also implemented WebRTC for native android app too. My signaling server is based on php WebSocket(Ratchet websocket). When I'm testing my implementation within two browsers(chrome-chrome, or chrome-firefox combination) I see the protocol is working fine. I mean video-audio call goes properly. When I test my android app I can see it's also working for app to app communication.

But the problem is when I'm trying to give call from my android app to web app I see the setRemoteDescription is not working rather it's generating the following error:

```
Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Media section has more than one track specified with a=ssrc lines which is not supported with Unified Plan.
```

In my gradle(app) script I implemented the WebRTC library as follows:

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'
```

That's why I think the latest `adapter.js`(for web part) and android library should be compatible and there are no issue related with version incompatibility between the web implementation and android implementation.

For better understanding I am sharing here the SDP message which is found when generating offer.

```
v=0
o=- 7452034467634633423 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=msid-semantic: WMS 90 BOLNAOPqVHAtxWW2PZJyA5RG9IkH2MntC2EP
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 0 8 105 13 110 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:KwHG
a=ice-pwd:YhH0S06F5dJrCns9jFbscFMA
a=ice-options:trickle renomination
a=fingerprint:sha-256 B1:75:DB:D5:20:8C:86:F1:CC:54:4A:1C:C6:C9:AD:D3:79:C4:1E:45:57:CD:9B:FC:CC:1D:01:C5:C1:C5:BF:93
a=setup:active
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:2787512374 cname:dF4uE3SebLpSsKGh
a=ssrc:2787512374 msid:90 101
a=ssrc:2787512374 mslabel:90
a=ssrc:2787512374 label:101
a=ssrc:4286803808 cname:dF4uE3SebLpSsKGh
a=ssrc:4286803808 msid:BOLNAOPqVHAtxWW2PZJyA5RG9IkH2MntC2EP cf5d6c28-239b-4c64-8051-33dbbb81edf4
a=ssrc:4286803808 mslabel:BOLNAOPqVHAtxWW2PZJyA5RG9IkH2MntC2EP
a=ssrc:4286803808 label:cf5d6c28-239b-4c64-8051-33dbbb81edf4
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 108 109 124
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:KwHG
a=ice-pwd:YhH0S06F5dJrCns9jFbscFMA
a=ice-options:trickle renomination
a=fingerprint:sha-256 B1:75:DB:D5:20:8C:86:F1:CC:54:4A:1C:C6:C9:AD:D3:79:C4:1E:45:57:CD:9B:FC:CC:1D:01:C5:C1:C5:BF:93
a=setup:active
a=mid:1
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:10 http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:108 red/90000
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 1166964128 3959308542
a=ssrc:1166964128 cname:dF4uE3SebLpSsKGh
a=ssrc:1166964128 msid:90 100
a=ssrc:1166964128 mslabel:90
a=ssrc:1166964128 label:100
a=ssrc:3959308542 cname:dF4uE3SebLpSsKGh
a=ssrc:3959308542 msid:90 100
a=ssrc:3959308542 mslabel:90
a=ssrc:3959308542 label:100
a=ssrc-group:FID 1617372799 1848430645
a=ssrc:1617372799 cname:dF4uE3SebLpSsKGh
a=ssrc:1617372799 msid:BOLNAOPqVHAtxWW2PZJyA5RG9IkH2MntC2EP b4a261f3-065b-47bd-a759-207401cb9a6e
a=ssrc:1617372799 mslabel:BOLNAOPqVHAtxWW2PZJyA5RG9IkH2MntC2EP
a=ssrc:1617372799 label:b4a261f3-065b-47bd-a759-207401cb9a6e
a=ssrc:1848430645 cname:dF4uE3SebLpSsKGh
a=ssrc:1848430645 msid:BOLNAOPqVHAtxWW2PZJyA5RG9IkH2MntC2EP b4a261f3-065b-47bd-a759-207401cb9a6e
a=ssrc:1848430645 mslabel:BOLNAOPqVHAtxWW2PZJyA5RG9IkH2MntC2EP
a=ssrc:1848430645 label:b4a261f3-065b-47bd-a759-207401cb9a6e
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

`rtcConfiguration.sdpSemantics = PeerConnection.SdpSemantics.PLAN_B;`

From the error: "Media section has more than one track specified with a=ssrc lines which is **not supported with Unified Plan.**"

Fwiw Unified plan is the default (I believe) and is set with

`rtcConfiguration.sdpSemantics = PeerConnection.SdpSemantics.UNIFIED_PLAN;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If it was not a long gap I would try your suggestion. However your answer may helps others who are currently working or for me in future. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. WebRTC for Android is so poorly documented that hopefully this will save someone else a small amount of pain :)

Comment: I hope your answer saves many from getting pain :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks. it works

if(getChromeVersion()>=72){ configuration.sdpSemantics = "unified-plan";} else { configuration.sdpSemantics = "plan-b";}

Comment: looks like this is not considered as answer? please elaborate your answer :pray:

Comment: Please make more obvious which post or comment it is you are saying thanks for. It is currently impossible to tell.